# Why does the ^ operator not work for expontentiation?

Tags: c++, operators, xor, exponentiation

I am trying to compute euclidean distances between points. This code compiles and runs but does not output the correct distances.

```
for (int z = 0; z < spaces_x; z++)
{
    double dist = sqrt( abs( ((spaces[z][0]-x)^2) + ((spaces[z][1]-y)^2) ) );
    cout << "for x "    << spaces[z][0] <<
            " for y "   << spaces[z][1] <<
            " dist is  "<< dist << endl;

    if (dist < min_dist)
    {
        min_dist = dist;
        index = z;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I don't see a question.  Looking quickly at the code, though, abs(dist) is pointless, since you are adding two squared numbers anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted to close this. It's fairly obvious what was being asked. I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 21):

The syntax `^ 2` does not mean raise to the power of 2 - it means XOR. Use `x * x`.

```
double dx = spaces[z][0] - x;
double dy = spaces[z][1] - y;
double dist2 = dx * dx + dy * dy;
```

Comment: +1. Also, dist=abs(dist) is unnecessary. A sum of two powers will always be positive.

Answer (score 8):

It may be a better idea to use `hypot()` instead of manually squaring and adding and taking a the square root. `hypot()` takes care of a number of cases where naive approach would lose precision. It is a part of C99 and C++0x, and for the compilers that don't have it, there's always [boost.math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/powers/hypot.html).

Comment: Or just leave it as distance squared for this calculation. The item with the smallest distance will also have the smallest distance squared.

Answer (score 6):

`^` is the `xor` operator; it does not perform exponentiation.

In the general case, if you want to raise something to a power, you should use the `std::pow` function.  However, in this specific case, since it is the square, you're probably better off just using multiplication (e.g., `x * x` instead of `std::pow(x, 2)`).

Comment: std::pow will use a shortcut if you call it with an integer for the power.

Comment: I've seen at least a couple implementations of pow that are rather poor and don't do any such optimization. In general don't count on it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in C++ the caret (`^`) is not an exponentiation operator.  Rather, it's a bitwise exclusive or.

Comment: It's called a "caret," not a carrot :)

Comment: It's bitwise *xor*, not *or*.

Comment: Wow, two careless mistakes in a single post. Sorry, fixed.